# Entity Framework 5 CRUD on entity linked to a view (.Net 4.5)

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a view on a production table:

```
CREATE VIEW view_Customers AS
    SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName
    FROM dbo.Customers
```

And I have a comments table that stores only one comment at a time for a given customer.  Not all customers will have a comment entered:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerComments
(
    CustomerID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , Comment VARCHAR(MAX)
CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerComments] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (CustomerID ASC)
)
```

The view is related to the table in my model with a 1 to 0/1 relationship and is intended solely to provide the user with a list of customers to which a comment should be related.

I've tried to set up a data entry form by dragging the view_Customers entity onto the form as a datagridview and its related CustomerComments entity as a details group and setting the bindingsource to the view.  The customers and any existing related comments below are displayed as I move through the Customers datagridview, but comments I enter in the Comments textbox below are not saved, even in state when navigating between customers, much less when the SaveChanges() method is called.

The code for creating the context and binding to it is as follows:

```
public partial class Customer_Comments : Form
{
    private CustomerEntities ctx;

    public Customer_Comments()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ctx = new CustomerEntities();

        bindingSourceView_Customers.DataSource = ctx.view_Customers.ToList();
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnSaveClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        ctx.Dispose();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

I've also tried starting with the CustomerComments entity and dragging in its related Customers entity (and changed the bindingsource.datasource as appropriate), but that doesn't even show the existing comments.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  The examples I'm able to find online all seem to deal with data sources based on hard-coded LINQ queries, rather than strongly typed entities.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And how do you add the entities to your context? You do SaveChanges but if entities have not been added then SaveChanges is a no-op and I don't see in your code a single .Add().

Comment: I guess that's part of my question, too.  When I click Add on the bindingnavigator control, a row is added to the datagridview for the view.  I would like to select a customer in the datagridview control and enter comments in the comments textbox below.  I'm trying to figure out how to make that happen. Also edited my code to eliminate contradiction.